# Calculate stream locations and Strahler order from DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga, stream-order

I am trying to locate streams and determine their order in QGIS. I have tried using several of the procedures described in answers to similar questions, but none of them seem to work. I have filled the sinks in my DEM, and then none of processes produce valid results. They either do not create the layers at all, or when the layers are created there are areas of internal flow that do not exist in the real world. I have GRASS included in the QGIS distribution on my Linux OS, and SAGA on my Windows OS, but neither of them contain both. I would prefer to do this process in either one or the other, but I can utilize tools from both if necessary.

Comment: The GRASS-GIS combined procedure of `r.watershed` and then `r.stream.extract` works quite well. What have you tried in GRASS?

Comment: BTW: no sink-filling needed for `r.watershed` in GRASS GIS.